# ¿Cómo hacer que el menú de mi página ocupe el ancho de pantalla?

Tags: css, menú

Buen día
Para empezar quiero aclarar que no soy programador ni tengo conocimientos a fondo en HTML ni CSS, estoy en el proceso de aprendizaje y he descubierto varias cosas que necesitaba, sin embargo esto si me está dando lucha. En la página que relaciono anexa no logro hacer que el menú ocupe el ancho de la pantalla independientemente de la resolución y de el número de item que tenga, a futuro incluiré mas opciones en el menú y cada una tiene distinta longitud de texto. Agradezco mucho su colaboración.

Comment: Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

[image: Aqui tienes el resultado]Usando 100vw como el ancho del menu
de esta manera:

```
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
left: auto;
float: none;
vertical-align: middle;
width: 100vw;
```

Answer (score 0):

No sé si no has conocido bootstrap, framework css utilizado en diseño, pero ofrece un sistema de colocación muy util basado en columnas y filas...
te dejo la documentacion a mano, muy sencilla basada en ejemplos.
ver, entender, copiar y modificar, muy simple...
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Para que lo entiendas, creas una caja 'row' que ocupe todo el ancho de la pantalla, y ese row lo puedes dividir hasta en 12 columnas 'cols' donde podras colocar...

navegador | contenido 1 | contenido2 | aside

te recomiendo que lo utilices, de veras. te dejo un ejemplo hecho por mi.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <p>Navegador</p>
    </div>            
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <p>Contenido</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Te dejo la descarga, de verdad, que el posicionamiento nunca fue tan fácil.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/download/